# Geocoding in android returns null value

Tags: google-maps, android-emulator, geocoding

i am doing geocoding in android get location from edittext and convert it into lat long and display on map but my address variable and list and has null values my address is like beauty Box A-9/1

my code is

```
     Geocoder gc =  new Geocoder(this);
      Address d ;
      double latitude = 0 ;
      double longitude = 0;

      try {
          List<Address>locname = gc.getFromLocationName(name, 5);

            d = locname.get(0);
            latitude = d.getLatitude();
            longitude= d.getLongitude();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GeoPoint dest = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6), (int)(longitude*1E6));
```

the locname is null i have tried many thing but no help

Comment: What is name, in your test case? Do you have Android manifest set up to give you internet connection permissions?

Comment: string name = edittext.gettext().tostring(); yes internet permission are given

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" ></uses-permission>


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Comment: The description of Geocoder states regarding the return, "a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available." So can you post the value of `name`? Does it work for some very obvious ones, like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043" ?

Comment: i enter the destination name in google maps it gives result and showed the desired destination but emulator it doesnot work

Comment: kindly tell me is geocoding can show result in emulator?

Comment: still cannot figure out the problem :(

Comment: Hi did you ever figure out the cause?